# pandas.apply function returns <built-in method

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert timestamps to string dates in a dataframe proceeding this way:

```
def ts_to_date(ts):
    return str(ts.date)

display(table["event_date_and_time"].apply(ts_to_date))
```

The issue is that the resulting pandas serie is filled with **built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...** and not with the converted timestamps. What do I do wrong ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `table["event_date_and_time"] = table["event_date_and_time"].astype(str)`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the parantheses after .date :

```
def ts_to_date(ts):
    return str(ts.date())
```

Comment: IMO, don't use `apply`, it's an inefficient loop. Use @roganjosh's comment.